# How to estimate the fuel required to send 1 kg to lower mars orbit?

Tags: propulsion, fuel, rocket-equation

Imagine a rocket with a payload of 1 kg. How much liquid fuel would be required to send that 1 kg payload to lower mars orbit. (1 kg is just the payload not the whole dry mass of the rocket) I want the full calculation. And also what are the things I should know to calculate this.

Comment: Lookup a “delta V map of the solar system”.  Propellant requirements for a mission are fundamentally related to the change in velocity required.  For example: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_system_delta_v_map.svg

Comment: Answering this question requires a lot of details not provided such as the mass of the spaceship, the type of engines, ISP, type of transfer orbit, etc.

Comment: This is an alright question, but it needs more details.  At the moment, it's like asking "How much fuel do I need to get from Barcelona to Cairo," but without specifying if you are travelling by air, sea, train, car, bus, foot, cycle...?  You need to either specify How you want to get to Mars, or ask what is the _minimum_ fuel and associated architecture.

Comment: There is a clear answer. Exotic trajectories are presumably not in scope, so hohmann transfers. The deltaV maps are made of hohmann transfers, so use the deltaV from leo to mars. Assume inert mass fraction and number of stages and calculate.

Comment: Hi Shardul, you should also state whether the launch is from Earth or from Mars.